# Adwhirl ad not receive issue

Tags: objective-c, ios, adwhirl

In my application , i have integrate Adwhirl . i have registered in 3 more networks like iAd, Admob and Google AdSense. its working fine. but in some case

```
-(void)adWhirlDidFailToReceiveAd:(AdWhirlView *)adWhirlView usingBackup:(BOOL)yesOrNo
{
    NSLog(@"Ad Not received");
    CGRect tempFrame = adView.frame;
    tempFrame.origin.y = -adView.frame.size.height;
    adView.frame = tempFrame;
}
```

is execute. some ad are not received properly i need to known the URL or network name of the Displaying AD. is it possible? if yes please help me to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably not a technical problem, this sounds like a problem of lack of inventory for the ads. You're not going to receive ads 100% of the time you receive them in your application unfortunately. If you check the `yesOrNo` boolean though, you can tell if AdWhirl is requesting another ad in the background.